# key mismatch error while generating a certificate using my own CA in Python's cryptography module

Tags: python-3.x, openssl, python-cryptography

I have code written in `Python`'s `Cryptography` module that does the following:

a) generate `rootCA` and root certificate

b) generate a client key

c) create a `Certificate Signing Request` using the key

d) use the `rootCA` generated in the first step, and the `CSR` created in the third step, to generate a certificate signed by my self-created root.

The code that does this looks like the following:

```
from cryptography import x509
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes, serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import load_der_private_key
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa
from cryptography.x509.oid import NameOID
import datetime
import uuid
import os
import sys
import subprocess

def generate_root_CA():
    """
    a) generate rootCA key
    b) generate rootCA crt
    """

    ##generating root key

    root_private_key = rsa.generate_private_key(
    public_exponent=65537,
    key_size=2048,
    backend=default_backend())


    ##self-sign and generate the root certificate

    root_public_key = root_private_key.public_key()
    builder = x509.CertificateBuilder()
    builder = builder.subject_name(x509.Name([
    x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.COMMON_NAME, u'Test CA'),
    x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.ORGANIZATION_NAME, u'Org'),
    x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.ORGANIZATIONAL_UNIT_NAME, u'Testing unit'),
    ]))

    builder = builder.issuer_name(x509.Name([
    x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.COMMON_NAME, u'Test CA'),
    ]))
    builder = builder.not_valid_before(datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=1))
    builder = builder.not_valid_after(datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 31))
    builder = builder.serial_number(int(uuid.uuid4()))
    builder = builder.public_key(root_public_key)
    builder = builder.add_extension(
    x509.BasicConstraints(ca=True, path_length=None), critical=True,)

    root_certificate = builder.sign(
        private_key=root_private_key, algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
        backend=default_backend()
    )


    ##write to disk

    with open("rootCA.key", "wb") as f:
        f.write(root_private_key.private_bytes(
            encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
            format=serialization.PrivateFormat.TraditionalOpenSSL,
            encryption_algorithm=serialization.BestAvailableEncryption(b"passphrase")
        ))

    with open("rootCA.crt", "wb") as f:
        f.write(root_certificate.public_bytes(
            encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
        ))

    return root_private_key, root_certificate

def generate_key():
    """
    a) generate key for the certificate being created
    """
    key = rsa.generate_private_key(
        public_exponent=65537,
        key_size=2048,
        backend=default_backend()
    )

    return key

def generate_csr(key, domain_name):
    """
    generate csr for the client certificate
    """
    csr = x509.CertificateSigningRequestBuilder().subject_name(x509.Name([
    # Provide various details about who we are.
        x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.COUNTRY_NAME, u"US"),
        x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.STATE_OR_PROVINCE_NAME, u"MA"),
        x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.LOCALITY_NAME, u"Boston"),
        x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.ORGANIZATION_NAME, u"Org"),
        x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.COMMON_NAME, domain_name),
    ])).add_extension(
        x509.SubjectAlternativeName([
        x509.DNSName(domain_name),
        x509.DNSName(u"www." + domain_name),
    ]),
    critical=False,

    # Sign the CSR with our private key.
    ).sign(key, hashes.SHA256(), default_backend())

    # Write our CSR out to disk.
    with open(domain_name + ".csr", "wb") as f:
        f.write(csr.public_bytes(serialization.Encoding.PEM))

    return csr

def sign_certificate_request(csr, rootkey, rootcrt, client_key, domain_name):
    """
    generate the certificate based on the csr created
    """


    crt = x509.CertificateBuilder().subject_name(
        csr.subject
    ).issuer_name(
        rootcrt.subject
    ).public_key(
        csr.public_key()
    ).serial_number(
        uuid.uuid4().int  # pylint: disable=no-member
    ).not_valid_before(
        datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    ).not_valid_after(
        datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(days=2)
    ).add_extension(
        extension=x509.KeyUsage(
            digital_signature=True, key_encipherment=True, content_commitment=True,
            data_encipherment=False, key_agreement=False, encipher_only=False, decipher_only=False, key_cert_sign=False, crl_sign=False
        ),
        critical=True
    ).add_extension(
        extension=x509.BasicConstraints(ca=False, path_length=None),
        critical=True
    ).add_extension(
        extension=x509.AuthorityKeyIdentifier.from_issuer_public_key(rootkey.public_key()),
        critical=False
    ).sign(
        private_key=rootkey,
        algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
        backend=default_backend()
    )

    with open(domain_name + ".crt", 'wb') as f:
        f.write(crt.public_bytes(encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM)) 



def main():

    domain_name = "domain.org"
    root_key, root_crt = generate_root_CA()
    domain_key = generate_key()
    csr = generate_csr(domain_key, domain_name)
    sign_certificate_request(csr, root_key, root_crt, domain_key, domain_name)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

However, I am getting the `ssl.SSLError: [X509: KEY_VALUES_MISMATCH] key values mismatch (_ssl.c:2798)` error when I test this using a local `flask` app. I cannot figure out the error. While signing the certificate, I am using the root certificate's private key, and my domain's public key as another argument, is that something that could be causing the problem?

EDIT:

I was able to check whether there was indeed an error producing the keys by the following two instructions (quote from the link) in this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/ssl-library-error-185073780-key-values-mismatch):

```
1- first command for getting the decryption of your server certificate: 
openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in /etc/yourcertificate.crt | openssl md5 

2- 2nd command for your (RSA) private key you got from creating csr:
openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in /etc/private.key | openssl md5
```

They were indeed different. There was some error transferring the proper keys, and I was able to rerun the code to get the `md5` as the same.